# ECONNREFUSED when connecting to Mongolab from a deployed heroku app

Tags: heroku, mlab, angular-fullstack

I developed a web page with the angular-fullstack generator and tried deploying it to Heroku following the instructions listed in the generator's github page.

I added the mongolab add-on and restarted the server but I always get the following log lines after a restart:

> 2016-05-02T17:16:57.742152+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
>
> 2016-05-02T17:17:01.929260+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server/app.js`
>
> 2016-05-02T17:17:06.396597+00:00 app[web.1]: Express server listening on 41865, in production mode
>
> 2016-05-02T17:17:06.405342+00:00 app[web.1]: MongoDB connection error: MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
>
> 2016-05-02T17:17:07.516482+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 255
>
> 2016-05-02T17:17:07.525635+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

So I went around looking for similar issues but most them talked about including the process.env.MONGOLAB_URI property in the configs, which I already had. By the way these are the configs I have under server/config:

server/config/environment/index.js

```
'use strict';

var path = require('path');
var _ = require('lodash');

function requiredProcessEnv(name) {
  if (!process.env[name]) {
    throw new Error('You must set the ' + name + ' environment variable');
  }
  return process.env[name];
}

// All configurations will extend these options
// ============================================
var all = {
  env: process.env.NODE_ENV,

  // Root path of server
  root: path.normalize(__dirname + '/../../..'),

  // Server port
  port: process.env.PORT || 9000,

  // Server IP
  ip: process.env.IP || '0.0.0.0',

  // Should we populate the DB with sample data?
  seedDB: false,

  // Secret for session, you will want to change this and make it an environment variable
  secrets: {
    session: 'copaamerica-secret'
  },

  // MongoDB connection options
  mongo: {
    options: {
      db: {
        safe: true
      }
    }
  },

  facebook: {
    clientID:     process.env.FACEBOOK_ID || 'id',
    clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_SECRET || 'secret',
    callbackURL:  (process.env.DOMAIN || '') + '/auth/facebook/callback'
  },

  twitter: {
    clientID:     process.env.TWITTER_ID || 'id',
    clientSecret: process.env.TWITTER_SECRET || 'secret',
    callbackURL:  (process.env.DOMAIN || '') + '/auth/twitter/callback'
  },

  google: {
    clientID:     process.env.GOOGLE_ID || 'id',
    clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET || 'secret',
    callbackURL:  (process.env.DOMAIN || '') + '/auth/google/callback'
  }
};

// Export the config object based on the NODE_ENV
// ==============================================
module.exports = _.merge(
  all,
  require('./shared'),
  require('./' + process.env.NODE_ENV + '.js') || {});
```

server/config/environment/production.js

```
'use strict';

// Production specific configuration
// =================================
module.exports = {
  // Server IP
  ip:     process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP ||
          process.env.IP ||
          undefined,

  // Server port
  port:   process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT ||
          process.env.PORT ||
          8080,

  // MongoDB connection options
  mongo: {
    uri:  process.env.MONGOLAB_URI ||
          process.env.MONGOHQ_URL ||
          process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL +
          process.env.OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME ||
          'mongodb://localhost/copaamerica'
  }
};
```

and
server/config/express.js

```
/**
 * Express configuration
 */

'use strict';

import express from 'express';
import favicon from 'serve-favicon';
import morgan from 'morgan';
import compression from 'compression';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import methodOverride from 'method-override';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import errorHandler from 'errorhandler';
import path from 'path';
import lusca from 'lusca';
import config from './environment';
import passport from 'passport';
import session from 'express-session';
import connectMongo from 'connect-mongo';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
var MongoStore = connectMongo(session);

export default function(app) {
  var env = app.get('env');

  app.set('views', config.root + '/server/views');
  app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
  app.set('view engine', 'html');
  app.use(compression());
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use(methodOverride());
  app.use(cookieParser());
  app.use(passport.initialize());

  // Persist sessions with MongoStore / sequelizeStore
  // We need to enable sessions for passport-twitter because it's an
  // oauth 1.0 strategy, and Lusca depends on sessions
  app.use(session({
    secret: config.secrets.session,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: false,
    store: new MongoStore({
      mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection,
      db: process.env.MONGOLAB_URI
    })
  }));

  /**
   * Lusca - express server security
   * https://github.com/krakenjs/lusca
   */
  if ('test' !== env) {
    app.use(lusca({
      csrf: {
        angular: true
      },
      xframe: 'SAMEORIGIN',
      hsts: {
        maxAge: 31536000, //1 year, in seconds
        includeSubDomains: true,
        preload: true
      },
      xssProtection: true
    }));
  }

  app.set('appPath', path.join(config.root, 'client'));

  if ('production' === env) {
    app.use(favicon(path.join(config.root, 'client', 'favicon.ico')));
    app.use(express.static(app.get('appPath')));
    app.use(morgan('dev'));
  }

  if ('development' === env) {
    app.use(require('connect-livereload')());
  }

  if ('development' === env || 'test' === env) {
    app.use(express.static(path.join(config.root, '.tmp')));
    app.use(express.static(app.get('appPath')));
    app.use(morgan('dev'));
    app.use(errorHandler()); // Error handler - has to be last
  }
}
```

any help would be great and I thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I found out what the problem was. The env variable that heroku sets up for the DB connection is called MONGODB_URI, but the angular-fullstack app expects a MONGOLAB_URI. Add process.env.MONGODB_URI wherever MONGOLAB_URI is and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking into this much, my immediate thought was whether or not you have CORS set up. Try doing a npm install cors

```
var express = require('express')
  , cors = require('cors')
  , app = express();

app.use(cors());

app.get('/products/:id', function(req, res, next){
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for all origins!'});
});

app.listen(80, function(){
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the input but the issue was related to variable naming. Check my reply.

Comment: No problem, glad you got it fixed!